# Is the javascript function I wrote is correct according to the question? I am the beginner

Tags: javascript, function, web, implementation

The function should calculate the total amount of pet food that the store should order for the upcoming week. The `numAnimals` parameter represents the number of animals in the store, and `avgFood` represents the average amount of food (in kilograms) eaten by each animal each week.

The function should return the total amount of pet food that should be ordered for the upcoming week, or -1 if `numAnimals` or `avgFood` is less than 0 or non-numeric.

```
function calculateFoodOrder(numAnimals, avgFood) {
// IMPLEMENT THIS FUNCTION!
if (numAnimals < 0 || avgFood < 0 || null) {
    return -1;
}
else {
    return totalAmount = avgFood * numAnimals;
}
```

}

Comment: `|| null` is wrong. You need an actual non-numeric test.

Comment: Please do not ask assignment questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

To check if a variable is numeric, you should check its type first:

```js
typeof num === 'number'
```

And bear in mind that `typeof NaN === 'number'`, but obviously it is should be excluded.

So the full implement may looks like:

```js
function calculateFoodOrder(numAnimals, avgFood) {
  // IMPLEMENT THIS FUNCTION!
  if (isInvalid(numAnimals) || isInvalid(avgFood)) return -1
  return avgFood * numAnimals;

  function isInvalid (num) {
    return typeof num !== 'number' || Number.isNaN(num) || num < 0
  }
}
```